# Keepass does not respect GTK_THEME variable

Tags: theme, mono, compatibility

I am using Cinnamon on Arch Linux with a dark theme (specifically [Vertex Dark](https://github.com/horst3180/vertex-theme)). The dark theme leads to undesirable behavior in [some apps](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=519763) where the foreground color is hard-coded to a dark color but the background color uses system colors.

One way around this is to create a `~/.local/share/applications/<myapp>.desktop` file which [sets a different GTK theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8336/how-can-one-make-firefox-ignore-my-gtk-theme-entirely). However, [Keepass](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KeePass) doesn't seem to be respecting the `GTK_THEME` environment variable. In the shell, if I try:

```
env GTK_THEME="Vertex" keepass
```

The Keepass theme doesn't seem to change at all. I suspect that this is because Keepass uses Mono for cross-platform support, which has some rough edges and doesn't always behave like native applications. Is there a different variable that I should be setting for Mono apps?

(Note that there appears to be a similar unanswered question on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/922397/change-appearance-of-a-mono-application)).

**Edit:** Looking into this a bit more, it seems that [KeepassXC](https://keepassxc.org/) has really matured since I last looked, so switching to a naive application is a feasible option. However, I'm still interested in learning whether or not there is something that can be done.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem and fixed it by setting the `GTK2_RC_FILES` variable like this: `GTK2_RC_FILES="/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc" keepass`

Comment: Although this should be the proper solution, unfortunately this does not work on debian buster with Gnome 3.30. The Internet does not seem to know why that is.